# How can i edit both video and animation in blender 2.9?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I have an intro saved as an mp4 and i want it to fade out and in the meanwhile fade in the animation i previously made in blender with a 3d model. How can i do it in fewest steps possible?

Comment: In the top right corner use Scenes and open up the vse to edit the scenes and add in video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zrm_XMfT6CA Here is a good video

Answer (score 0):

Open your model.

Add a new scene.

In the new scene open VSE, hit Shift+A and import your video.

Add a Scene strip using the name of the scene containing your model.

Make the two strips overlap where you want the crossfade.

Then add a crossfade.